# How to get View ID for Property in order to consume Google Analytics Reporting API V4

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I have to fetch firebase analytics data from Google analytics reporting API v4 using C# for my mobile application.

When I created a project in firebase for storing analytics data in firebase, if for the same project If I check for ViewId in Admin section of firebase analytics. It is not showing any View and it's mandatory to query data.
If I create a new property and with that if I try to create view using advance settings, It is saying that this is applicable for web application only and it older way of using it.

Can someone help me how can I fetch firebase analytics data using C# library in my WebAPI project  without View ID and also without using Beta version of firebase API

Comment: Also How can I get custom events value using Dimensions and metrics in c#

Comment: Going to take a guess here but reporting api reads from universal analytics accounts.  Firebase writes to Ga4 accounts.   have you checked https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

Comment: @DaImTo I Have checked this and actually this is still in Beta phase.

Comment: Yes it is most of GA4 is still in beta.  That fact remains that if the data is in a Ga4 account then you need to use the [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)  The [Google analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) will only give you access to data stored in Universal analytics accounts.    [Firebase analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web) stores data in GA4

Comment: Yes Thanks for providing this solution. I think as of now we have only GA4 Beta version for this. And for using Custom Dimension and Metrics we need to create custom Dimensions and metrics in Google analytics account using event parameters